# Trying to make a Member Count Discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Here I am trying to make a Discord bot that counts how many members there are in a server then changes the name of a channel to 'Members: '.
Here is the code I have so far:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

});
client.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member){
  let myGuild = member.guild;
  let myChannel = myGuild.channels.cache.get("Channel ID Here");
  let memberNumber = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
  myChannel.name = `Members: ${memberNumber}`;
})

client.login('000000000000000000000000000000000');
```

The problem that I have is, I receive no errors, but the bot doesn't do anything when a new person is added, absolutely nothing. What do I need to make the bot change the name of the channel. Also, if anyone knows how to do this with a Discord bot, could you add in the code how to make the text channel where the bot should display the member count inaccessible, like you can see the name of the channel but if you click on it, nothing happens and you can't go into the channel.

Answer (score 0):

`myChannel.name` is simply a property, it cannot be changed directly. You need to call `.edit()` on the channel and pass in the new name.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

});
client.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member){
  let myGuild = member.guild;
  let myChannel = myGuild.channels.cache.get("Channel ID Here");
  let memberNumber = myGuild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size;
  myChannel.edit({ name: `Members: ${memberNumber}` });
})

client.login('000000000000000000000000000000000');
```

[Documentation on TextChannel#edit()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=edit)

Comment: I tried it, but it seems it's the same thing, nothing is happening

Comment: I tried `console.log(memberNumber)` before `myChannel.edit({ name: `Members: ${memberNumber}` })` to see what happens and nothing showed in the terminal even when I added someone to the server. I seems it doesn't detect that someone was added to the server or something like that and I don't know why.

Comment: Does your client log in and log a message to the terminal when you restart it? If it does log in you may need to enable the guild member intent, it's worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

You need to call an event for when a user joins **and** leaves the server:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member){
   memberCount(member);
});

client.on("guildMemberRemove", function(member){
    memberCount(member);
});

client.login('000000000000000000000000000000000');

function memberCount(member){
    let myGuild = member.guild;
    let myChannel = myGuild.channels.cache.get("Channel ID Here");
    let memberNumber = myGuild.memberCount;
    myChannel.setName({ name: `Members: ${memberNumber.toLocaleString()}` });
}
```

Make sure the bot has the priviledged Gateway intents.
Simply go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), and make sure you have checked `Presence Intent` & `Server Members Intent`.
e.g.
[image]

Comment: The bot works with no errors, but when I add or remove members nothing happens, even though the Bot has Admin permissions for the server and full permissions for the channel and category.

Comment: @Arian I have made some changes. If you still encounter this problem, maybe my new solution works for you.